# Pyspark Dataframe Format for FPGrowth use -> The input column must be array, but got bigint

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory, fpgrowth

while trying to get Data from an XLSX into the right format for FPGrowth i face following errormessage when running `model = fpGrowth.fit(pivotDF)`:

`IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The input column must be array, but got bigint.`

I take the data out of an XLSX file and read it in to a Pandas DataFrame and then convert it into a Spark Dataframe, do some cleaning and pivoting to get the desired table.

`pivotDF.printSchema()`
shows this:

```
 |-- SalesTransactionID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 0: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 3: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 4: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 5: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 6: long (nullable = true)
....
```

My Data (pivotDF) looks like this:

```
+------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|SalesTransactionID|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|
+------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|                 0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  6|  6|  0|
|                 1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  3|  0|
|                 2|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  2|  0|  0|  0|
|                 3|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|                 4|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Is there any way to convert/cast this into the needed array Type column?

Many Thanks in advance

Edit:
The goal i'm aiming for is something like this:

```
([(0, [7, 8]),
  (1, [8]), 
  (2, [6])], 
["id", "items"])
```

Comment: the array of what? all columns or single column?

Comment: I editet the question @Lamanus maybe its more clear what i want to get out of the data. So i suppose i want each column as an array with the SalesTransactionID as index.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am stuck into similar problem.